# {{ ansible_hostname }} not working while calling directly with Ansible 2.3

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-facts

Has anyone faced the following issue with `"{{ ansible_hostname }}"` while calling in a playbook task directly?

Please suggest if there is other way around to do it or if I'm doing anything wrong here, I have tried it with both `lineinfile` & `replace` module:

```
---
- name: Playbook to Install CollectD
  hosts: servercast01
  gather_facts: False
  remote_user: root
  become: true
  tasks:
  - name: Replacing hostname entry
    lineinfile:
      dest: "/tmp/collectd/etc/collectd.conf"
      regexp: '#Hostname  "myvm01"'
      line: 'Hostname  "{{ ansible_hostname }}"'
```

2) With `replace` module:

```
---
- name: Playbook to Install CollectD
  hosts: servercast01
  gather_facts: False
  remote_user: root
  become: true
  tasks:
  - name: Replacing hostname entry
    replace:
      dest: /tmp/collectd/etc/collectd.conf
      regexp: '#Hostname  "myvm01"'
      replace: 'Hostname  "{{ ansible_hostname }}"'
      backup: yes
```

> Below is the error while executing the playbook..

```
fatal: [servercast01]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "the field 'args' has an invalid value, which appears to include a variable that is undefined. The error was: 'ansible_hostname' is undefined\n\nThe error appears to have been in '/etc/ansible/lineinfile3.yml': line 10, column 5, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n  tasks:\n  - name: Replacing hostname entry\n    ^ here\n"}
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`ansible_hostname` is a fact and you have explicitly disabled gathering facts (`gather_facts: False`), so it's not defined.

Remove the line.

Comment: in my case `gather_facts: true` but still doesn't collect it, it is caused when I use `--tags` if i'm not - it works

Answer (score 0):

You can also get the hostname as defined in the inventory with.

```
{{ inventory_hostname }} or {{ inventory_hostname_short }}
```

This does not require gather_facts.